# Draw Coupled Oscillators in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, circuitikz

I am new in Tikz, any idea how can I draw the following figure in Tikz and in general coupled oscillators in Tikz? [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Maybe the [`circuitikz` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) has what you need?

Comment: Thanks! I will try circuitikz package

Comment: Hmmm, not exactly a `circuitikz` task (but you can leverage a `cute inductor` shape...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is not a circuit, you can leverage the shapes of `circuitikz` to draw something similar. The basic idea is to use a `cute inductor` as the shape for the spring, and "poles" for the connections. The basic shapes are, though, quite different from what you want:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[cute inductor, o-o] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...but we can tweak it. For example, we can grow the width of the coil and the number of "twists" and try to find numbers that fill all the space (by trial and error...); adding `inductors/coils=9, inductors/width=1.4` you have:

[image]

The extremes are fine because the poles (the white dots) are drawn *above* the component and filled. So I can now grow them, for example with `nodes width=0.1`:

[image]

and now it's practically done, you can just use Ti*k*Z lines and normal shapes.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[cute inductor,
        inductors/coils=9, inductors/width=1.4,
        nodes width=0.1, l=$s$, 
        o-o] (2,0);
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,2) node[left, midway]{$l$};
    \draw (2,0) -- ++(0,2) node[right, midway]{$l$};
    \draw (0,-.5) node[flowarrow, label=below:$y$]{};
    \draw (2,-.5) node[flowarrow, label=below:$x$]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It works only because of "dirty details" on how the path is built and adjusting the lengths by trial and error...

(If you want the vertical line to stay under the white circles, just draw them before the coil.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. For me, it solved the issue even in force using circuitikz package

Comment: Now it's a proper answer! You can upvote and accept it if you think it's helpful!

Comment: I already upvote it! Thanks a lot for your help :)